# Not able to save large spark dataframe as pickle

Tags: pandas, pyspark, hdfs

I have large dataframe (little more than 20G), trying to save that as pickle object to be later used in the another process.

I have tried different configuration, below are the latest one.

```
executor_cores=4                                                                
executor_memory='20g'                                                           
driver_memory='40g'                                                                
deploy_mode='client'                                                            
max_executors_dynamic='spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=400'                   
num_executors_static=300                                                        
spark_driver_memoryOverhead='5g'                                                 
spark_executor_memoryOverhead='2g'                                               
spark_driver_maxResultSize='8g'                                                 
spark_kryoserializer_buffer_max='1g'
```

Note:- I cannot increase spark_driver_maxResultSize more than 8G.

I have also tried saving dataframe as hdfs files and then tried to save it as pickel but getting same error messsage as earlier.

My understanding is, when we use pandas.pickle it brings all the data into one driver and then create pickle object. As data size is more than driver_max_result_size code is failing. (Code has worked earlier for 2G data).

Do we have any worksround to solve this problem?

```py
big_data_frame.toPandas().to_pickle('{}/result_file_01.pickle'.format(result_dir))

big_data_frame.write.save('{}/result_file_01.pickle'.format(result_dir), format='parquet', mode='append')

df_to_pickel=sqlContext.read.format('parquet').load(file_path) 
df_to_pickel.toPandas().to_pickle('{}/scoring__{}.pickle'.format(afs_dir, rd.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
```

## Error message

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1638.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 955 tasks (4.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)

Answer (score 2):

Saving as pickle file is an RDD function in Spark, not dataframe. To save your frame using pickle, run

```
big_data_frame.rdd.saveAsPickleFile(filename)
```

If you are working with big data, it is never a good idea to run either collect or toPandas in spark as it collects everything in memory, crashing the system. I would suggest you to use parquet or any other format for saving your data as RDD functions are in maintenance mode, which means spark is not introducing any new features to it rapidly.

To read the file, try

```
pickle_rdd = sc.pickleFile(filename).collect()
df = spark.createDataFrame(pickle_rdd)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. If I copy this file from hdfs to local, will the file integrity  remain intact?

Comment: Hi, saveAsPickleFile file worked but it has created adirectory in hdfs by the name of <file_name>.pickle.
This direcotry has multiple hdfs files, but I am not able to use "read_pickel" on this directory. 
I tried reading one part (ex. part-00199) from this direcotry, but again I get error as "insecure string pickle".
How to read data from this directory?
Note: I have copied data from HDFS to my edgenode.